How can I get these two PGF Charts to be centered on the page while being the same size?
So my Issue is that I cant get these two PGF Charts aligned in the middle of the page this also leads to the frustating outcome that the barchart on the right is squished. Document border are 3 cm on the left and 2 on the right. But it shouldnt be this far off. Anybody got an Idea? (Anchoring really didnt do anything)

\begin{figure}[H]

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{BAStatis1.csv}
\edef\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
title=\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{\small\centering
            Anteil der Jugendlichen im Alter von 10-14 in einer Gemeinde im Landkreis München},
/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={},
width=0.3\linewidth,height=17cm,
xbar,/pgf/bar shift=0pt,
xmin=0, xmax=8,
xtick=\empty,
enlarge x limits={value=0.1, upper},
enlarge y limits=0.1,
ytick={0,...,\numberofrows}, 
y dir=reverse,
xlabel= {},
y tick label style={major tick length=0pt},
yticklabels from table={BAStatis1.csv}{[index]0},
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align=horizontal,
anchor=southwest,
axis line style={draw=none},
]

\addplot [draw,fill=blue!50,discard if={Gemeinde }{Pullach }
] table [
    y expr=\coordindex,
    x index=1,col sep=comma
]{BAStatis1.csv};

\addplot [draw,fill=orange,discard if not={Gemeinde }{Pullach }] table [
    y expr=\coordindex,
    x index=1,col sep=comma
]{BAStatis1.csv};
\addplot [draw,fill=green,discard if not={Gemeinde }{Landkreis }] table [
    y expr=\coordindex,
    x index=1,col sep=comma
]{BAStatis1.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{BAStatis2.csv}
\edef\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
title=\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{\small\centering
            Anteil der Jugendlichen im Alter von 15-17 in einer Gemeinde im Landkreis München},
/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={},
width=0.3\linewidth,height=17cm,
xbar,/pgf/bar shift=0pt,
xmin=0, xmax=10,
xtick=\empty,
enlarge x limits={value=0.1, upper},
enlarge y limits=0.1,
ytick={0,...,\numberofrows}, 
y dir=reverse,
xlabel= {},
y tick label style={major tick length=0pt},
yticklabels from table={BAStatis2.csv}{[index]0},
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align=horizontal,
anchor=southwest,
axis line style={draw=none},
]

\addplot [draw,fill=blue!50,discard if={Gemeinde }{Pullach }
] table [
    y expr=\coordindex,
    x index=1,col sep=comma
]{BAStatis2.csv};

\addplot [draw,fill=orange,discard if not={Gemeinde }{Pullach }] table [
    y expr=\coordindex,
    x index=1,col sep=comma
]{BAStatis2.csv};
\addplot [draw,fill=green,discard if not={Gemeinde }{Landkreis }] table [
    y expr=\coordindex,
    x index=1,col sep=comma
]{BAStatis2.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

Here the CSV Data (I added one because they are more or less the same just with second set of numbers different and sorted slightly differentyl):
Gemeinde ,15-17
Baierbrunn ,3.9
Pullach ,3.8
Gräfelfing ,3.7
Grasbrunn ,3.7
Höhenbrunn ,3.7
Neuried ,3.7
Oberschleißheim ,3.5
Aying ,3.5
Schäftlarn ,3.5
Straßlach ,3.4
Grünwald ,3.3
Neubiberg ,3.3
Aschheim ,3.2
Brunnthal ,3.2
Feldkirchen ,3.2
Oberhaching ,3.2
Höhenkirchen-Sieg. ,3.1
Sauerlach ,3.1
Landkreis ,3.0
Putzbrunn ,2.9
Kirchheim ,2.8
Ottobrunn ,2.8
Planegg ,2.8
Haar ,2.7
Taufkirchen ,2.7
Unterschleißheim ,2.6
Ismaning ,2.5
Garching ,2.4
Unterhaching ,2.4
Unterföhring ,2.1


Sorry, don’t get your trouble. Contentwise the right part (pars) will be smaller, hence appear to be narrowed. // Without your .csv files (or a useful mockup) nobody can work with your code. // Also, nobody can compile it. // Please add. Thank you

I added one. Sorry my mistake.

Could you make a compilable example? Maybe you could set the bounding box yourself, this way you'd have complete control where the centre should end up.

To my observations, the sooner a question provides compilable code, the faster answers will come ... // Sometimes it's due because we have to guesswork preambles etc. At other times it's an act of cortesy thinking of all those volunteers here ...
